# Is this a selection sort?

Tags: sorting, selection-sort

I just came up with this sorting algorithm and it's different from other selection sorts that I've found on the internet. Can this be considered a selection sort?

```
for(mindex = 0; mindex < length; mindex++) {

    for(index = mindex + 1; index < length; index++) {
        if(array[mindex] > array[index]) {
            int temp = array[mindex];
            array[mindex] = array[index];
            array[index] = temp;
        }//End of swap
    }//End of index loop
}//End of main loop
```

Comment: That looks like bubblesort-ish.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to selection sort. You just do lots of extra swaps, which probably makes it slower.